# Update RecyclerView with DiffUtil and AsyncListDiffer not Working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils, android-asynclistdiffer

I'm creating a `RecyclerView` in `Fragment`using `DiffUtil` and `AsyncListDiffer` because I don't want to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method. But I'm facing a problem while using this approach. I'm trying to retrieve items from the database, but every time the data changes (increase) the UI won't update directly. I have to close my app first and then open it again or go to another class to check the updated item.

This is my adapter:

```
public class AdapterSaham extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements SectionIndexer, SearchFilter {
   public static final int SECTION_VIEW = 0;
   public static final int CONTENT_VIEW = 1;

   List<DaftarSaham> daftarSahamList;
   private ArrayList<Integer> mSectionPositions;
   private static int  lastClicked = -1;
   WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;
   private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
   private int lastPosition = -1;
   int row_index = -1;

   public AdapterSaham(ArrayList<DaftarSaham> daftarSaham, Context context, ItemClickListener clickListener){
       this.daftarSahamList = daftarSaham;
       this.mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<Context> ( context );
       this.itemClickListener = clickListener;
   }

   private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DaftarSaham> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DaftarSaham> () {
       @Override
       public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull DaftarSaham oldItem, @NonNull DaftarSaham newItem) {
           return newItem.getTicker ().equals ( oldItem.getTicker () ) && newItem.getCompanyName ().equals ( newItem.getCompanyName () );
       }

       @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
       @Override
       public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull DaftarSaham oldItem, @NonNull DaftarSaham newItem) {
           return newItem.equals ( oldItem );
       }

   };

   private  AsyncListDiffer<DaftarSaham> differ = new AsyncListDiffer<DaftarSaham> (this, DIFF_CALLBACK  );

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       Context ctx = mContextWeakReference.get ();
       View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.list_item,parent,false  );
      
   
      return new ItemViewHolder ( view, ctx , itemClickListener);

   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Context ctx = mContextWeakReference.get ();
       if (ctx == null){
           return;
       }
      
       ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder= (ItemViewHolder) holder;
       DaftarSaham daftarSaham =  differ.getCurrentList ().get ( position);
       itemViewHolder.txtTickerSaham.setText ( daftarSaham.getTicker () );
       itemViewHolder.txtCompanyName.setText ( daftarSaham.getCompanyName () );
   }

   public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       private TextView txtTickerSaham, txtCompanyName;
       private LinearLayout cardView;

       ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

       public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final Context context, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
           super ( itemView );
           txtTickerSaham = (TextView) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.tickerSaham );
           txtCompanyName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.tv_company_name );
           cardView = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.cvRecycler );

           this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

       }

   }

  @Override
   public int getItemCount() {

       return differ.getCurrentList ().size ();
   }

   public void submitList(List<DaftarSaham> newdataList){
       differ.submitList ( newdataList );
       daftarSahamList = new ArrayList<> (newdataList);
   }
```

Code in Fragment:

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=recyclerViewIndexer.getLayoutParams();
        params.height= h;
        recyclerViewIndexer.setLayoutParams(params);
        recyclerViewIndexer.setHasFixedSize ( true );
        recyclerViewIndexer.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( getContext ()) );

 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest ( Request.Method.GET, URL,
               new Response.Listener<String> () {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<> ();
                       try {
                           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (response);
                           JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray ( "data_emiten" );
                           for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length (); i++){
                               JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject ( i );
                               String ticker = jo.getString ( "ticker" );
                               String companyName = jo.getString ( "companyName" );
                               daftarNonSection.add ( new DaftarSaham (ticker, companyName, false) );

                           }

                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace ();
                       }

                       getHeaderListLetter ( daftarSahamList,daftarNonSection );
                       adapterSaham = new AdapterSaham ( daftarSahamList, getContext (), new AdapterSaham.ItemClickListener () {
                           @Override
                           public void onItemClick(Integer numbers, boolean isSelected) {
                               String ticker = "";
                               if (isSelected ){
                                   ticker = daftarSahamList.get ( Integer.valueOf ( numbers) ).ticker;
                               }
                               SlidingTab slidingTab = (SlidingTab) getActivity ();
                               slidingTab.setTicker (ticker);
                           }
                       } );
                       recyclerViewIndexer.setAdapter ( adapterSaham );
                       adapterSaham.submitList ( daftarSahamList );
                       Log.d ( "TAG", "onResponse: "+ response );
                   }
               },
               new Response.ErrorListener () {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       Log.d ( "TAG", "onErrorResponse: "+error );
                   }
               } );

       int socketTimeOut = 50000;
       RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy (socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
       stringRequest.setRetryPolicy ( policy );
       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue ( getContext () );
       requestQueue.add ( stringRequest );
   }
```

My model:

```
public class DaftarSaham implements Comparable<DaftarSaham> {

    public String ticker;
    public String companyName;
    public boolean isSection;
    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public DaftarSaham() {

    }

    public DaftarSaham(String ticker, String companyName, boolean isSection) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.isSection = isSection;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setTicker(String ticker) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }


    public String getTicker() {
        return ticker;
    }
 }
```

I don't know why it's not working because I have tried using `DiffUtil` and `AsyncListDiffer` before and there is no problem. Any helps or suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see from your code, you're probably misusing `DiffUtil.ItemCallback`. The purpose of `areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)` is two decide wheather two object represent the same item but in your code you're using `.equals` method, that is for **[content comparison](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20%3D%3D%20operators,of%20values%20in%20the%20objects.)**.
Within `areItemsTheSame` you should check items **id equality**, since you don't have ids, you could simply do the check by using `ticker` string, but be aware that if two items have the same `ticker` the two items will match:

```
public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull DaftarSaham oldItem, @NonNull DaftarSaham newItem) {
       return newItem.getTicker() == oldItem.getTicker()
}
```

Differently, `areContentsTheSame` checks whether two items have the same data and this method is called only if `areItemsTheSame` returns true. In here, you should probably check if class properties matches between the old and the new item, something like:

```java
public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull DaftarSaham oldItem, @NonNull DaftarSaham newItem) {
   return (newItem.getTicker() == oldItem.getTicker()) && (newItem.getCompanyName() == oldItem.getCompayName())
}
```

Be aware that `areContentsTheSame` business logic it's up to you, accordingly to the properties you identified to be part of the content. The standard approach is to use `.equals()` method, but doesn't seem to be your case.

```java
public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull DaftarSaham oldItem, @NonNull DaftarSaham newItem) {
   return (newItem.equals(oldItem))
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work, as far as you saw from my code did I do something wrong in my fragment?

Comment: Hard to say from the code in the question, do you want to share a repo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this step. After spending a huge time I found that it's because of empty list. When upating list do this ::

```
fun updateList(updatedList: List<Notification>) {
    if (updatedList.isEmpty()) {
        differ.submitList(emptyList())
        return
    }
    differ.submitList(updatedList)
}
```